# How to restore a standalone server from a pg_basebackup using the fetch option

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.6

I am attempting to make a backup & restore of a production Postgres server (9.6 Windows) for development testing. This server is standalone and does not need to do streaming replication.

I have used

```
.\pg_basebackup -Ft -Z 9 -D D:\pgbackup\default -P -U postgres -Xf --checkpoint=fast
```

I am using `-Xf` option since the database is quite large and I want to compress it. Using the option `-Xs` from the standby server is too slow, and using this option on primary server requires the tablespaces to be empty.

After backup the tar files are extracted into base and each tablespace. I've created a recovery.conf with single entry

```
standby_mode = off
```

Here is the postgres log

```
2021-06-17 15:54:46.463 CAT,,,8292,"::1:55731",60cb5426.2064,1,"",2021-06-17 15:54:46 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=::1 port=55731",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:46.464 CAT,"postgres","",8292,"::1:55731",60cb5426.2064,2,"",2021-06-17 15:54:46 CAT,,0,FATAL,57P03,"the database system is starting up",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:46.464 CAT,,,7788,,60cb5426.1e6c,1,,2021-06-17 15:54:46 CAT,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:51.474 CAT,,,2116,"::1:55736",60cb542b.844,1,"",2021-06-17 15:54:51 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=::1 port=55736",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:51.474 CAT,"postgres","",2116,"::1:55736",60cb542b.844,2,"",2021-06-17 15:54:51 CAT,,0,FATAL,57P03,"the database system is starting up",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:51.474 CAT,,,9524,,60cb542b.2534,1,,2021-06-17 15:54:51 CAT,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:56.464 CAT,,,10684,"::1:55740",60cb5430.29bc,1,"",2021-06-17 15:54:56 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=::1 port=55740",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:56.464 CAT,"postgres","",10684,"::1:55740",60cb5430.29bc,2,"",2021-06-17 15:54:56 CAT,,0,FATAL,57P03,"the database system is starting up",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:54:56.464 CAT,,,9528,,60cb5430.2538,1,,2021-06-17 15:54:56 CAT,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:55:01.469 CAT,,,7344,"::1:55742",60cb5435.1cb0,1,"",2021-06-17 15:55:01 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=::1 port=55742",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:55:01.469 CAT,"postgres","",7344,"::1:55742",60cb5435.1cb0,2,"",2021-06-17 15:55:01 CAT,,0,FATAL,57P03,"the database system is starting up",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 15:55:01.469 CAT,,,4820,,60cb5435.12d4,1,,2021-06-17 15:55:01 CAT,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
",,,,,,,,,""
```

What is the correct procedure to create a standalone backup?

**[UPDATE]**

After turning up log level, deleting recovery.conf and backup_label the database starts but the schemas are missing.

New log file

```
2021-06-17 17:04:30.002 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,1,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"ending log output to stderr",,"Future log output will go to log destination ""csvlog"".",,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.009 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,2,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"forked new backend, pid=2844 socket=5184",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.024 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,1,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying ""C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pg_stat_statements""",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.024 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,2,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying ""C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pg_stat_statements.dll""",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.025 CAT,,,2844,,60cb647e.b1c,1,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying ""C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pg_stat_statements""",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.025 CAT,,,2844,,60cb647e.b1c,2,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying ""C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pg_stat_statements.dll""",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.025 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,3,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"loaded library ""pg_stat_statements""",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,4,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"database system was shut down at 2021-06-17 17:04:00 CAT",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,5,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"mapped win32 error code 2 to 2",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,,,2844,,60cb647e.b1c,3,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"loaded library ""pg_stat_statements""",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,,,2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,4,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=55214",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,5,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,FATAL,57P03,"the database system is starting up",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,6,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.026 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,7,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,8,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(1): 1 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,9,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"exit(1)",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,10,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,11,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,"postgres","postgres",2844,"127.0.0.1:55214",60cb647e.b1c,12,"",2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,6,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"invalid checkpoint record",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,7,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,FATAL,XX000,"could not locate required checkpoint record",,"If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file ""D:/Wim/postgres-data/backup_label"".",,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,8,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(1): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,9,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(1): 4 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,10,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(1): 2 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,11,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"exit(1)",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,12,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,13,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.027 CAT,,,5900,,60cb647e.170c,14,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.028 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,3,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"reaping dead processes",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.028 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,4,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"server process (PID 2844) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.028 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,5,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"reaping dead processes",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.029 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,6,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"startup process (PID 5900) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.029 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,7,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"aborting startup due to startup process failure",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.029 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,8,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.029 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,9,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(1): 4 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.029 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,10,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"cleaning up dynamic shared memory control segment with ID 122495012",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.040 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,11,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(1): 2 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.040 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,12,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,LOG,00000,"database system is shut down",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.040 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,13,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"exit(1)",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.041 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,14,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.041 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,15,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.041 CAT,,,6012,,60cb647d.177c,16,,2021-06-17 17:04:29 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.041 CAT,,,3520,,60cb647e.dc0,1,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"logger shutting down",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.041 CAT,,,3520,,60cb647e.dc0,2,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(0): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.041 CAT,,,3520,,60cb647e.dc0,3,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"shmem_exit(0): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.042 CAT,,,3520,,60cb647e.dc0,4,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"proc_exit(0): 0 callbacks to make",,,,,,,,,""
2021-06-17 17:04:30.042 CAT,,,3520,,60cb647e.dc0,5,,2021-06-17 17:04:30 CAT,,0,DEBUG,00000,"exit(0)",,,,,,,,,""
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe recovery.conf only had the single entry as given above. Is there any other recovery config needed? Additionally, I have given the postgres log error.

Comment: You don't need recovery.conf at all in case of simple start from basebackup.

Comment: The interesting log messages must be before that. I suspect that `-Xf` didn't get all the required WAL. You'd have to use `-Xs`, and I don't see what could be slow about it.

Comment: I deleted the recovery.conf and backup_label and now i starts but the schema is missing. I also increased log level. I didnt use -Xs since in this PG version it must be in plain format, and thus tablespaces must be empty or mapped. There is a tablespace mapping bug in this PG version https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4e641357-69bb-d09b-9174-cb08facb94b8@gmail.com. -Xs was only slow because I had to do it from standby server and since the format is plain, it was taking a very long time

Comment: Why did you decide to remove backup_label?